# Seaborn tsplot - y-axis scale

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.tsplot(data = df_month, time = 'month', value = 'pm_local');
plt.show()
```

Using this code I get this blank plot, I presume because of the scale of the y-axis. I don't know why this is, here are the first 5 rows of my dataframe (which consists of 12 rows - 1 row for each month):
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you edit your code to be a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is related to the field `unit`. The function expects in the case of data passed as `DataFrame` a unit indicated which subject the data belongs to. This function behavior is not obvious for me, but see this example.

```
# Test Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
                   'value': [11.5, 9.7, 12, 8, 4, 12.3]})

# Added a custom unit with a value = 1
sns.tsplot(data=df, value='value', unit=[1]*len(df), time='month')

plt.show()
```

You can also use extract a `Series` and plot it.

```
sns.tsplot(data=df.set_index('month')['value'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. In my case it was due to incomplete data, such that every time point had at least one missing value, causing the default estimator to return NaN for every time point.

Since you only show the first 5 records of your data we can't tell if your data has the same issue. You can see if the following fix works:

```
from scipy import stats

sns.tsplot(data = df_month, time = 'month',
           value = 'pm_local',
           estimator = stats.nanmean);
```